# create as many entries in list as there is in another

Tags: c#

So ive created a list of clientAccountNames

```
 public IEnumerable<String> ClientAccount_Names { get; set; }
```

i've then used a service to get all the userLoginRecords and store them in the model.UserLoginRecords list

```
model.UserLoginRecords = _userService.GetFiltered(filter, _preferenceService.GetMaxRows(this.GetType()), null);
```

i've then calculated the no. of entires in the model.UserLoginRecords list

```
int numberOfUsers = model.UserLoginRecords.Count();
```

I then want to add as many entries as there is in the model.userloginrecord to the IEnumerable ClientAccount-Names found in the model

```
model.ClientAccount_Names = string.Empty X numberOfUsers;
```

how can i do the last part where i add as many entries as is found?

Comment: Blank entries? What's the point?

Comment: @Mansfield, default values when you're overwriting only part of them later? At least that was a use case for me recently with a similar problem.

Comment: so i can add entries to them after, i know what to add just need to know how many times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Enumerable.Range`

```
model.ClientAccount_Names = Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfUsers)
                                          .Select(r => string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Enumerable.Repeat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb348899.aspx):

```
model.ClientAccount_Names = Enumerable.Repeat(string.Empty, numberOfUsers);
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want to add empty strings?

```
model.ClientAccount_Names = new List<string>();
```

and then

```
for(int i=0; i < numberOfUsers; i++)
{
    model.ClientAccount_Names.Add("");
}
```

That should do it!